# <io.h>_filelength and _filelengthi64 always returns 0

Tags: c, windows

I am using low level io functions to fetch the size of a file in bytes and write it to stdout. I am using windows 7 64bit, and I am using visual studio 2017, x64 debugging mode. The functions _filelength and _filelengthi64 are exclusive to the windows operating system however when I use them they both return a 0 for any file I open. Here is the full code, but the issue should only lie with `_sopen_s()` or `_filelengthi64()`:

**Header**

```
#pragma once

// Headers
#include <io.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <share.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

//  Constants
#define stdout  1
#define stderr  2

//  Macros
#define werror_exit     { werror(); return 1; }
#define werr_exit(s)    { _write(stderr, (s), (unsigned int)strlen((s))); return 1; }

//  Declarations
extern void werror();
extern void wnum(__int64 num);
```

**Source**

```
#include "readbinaryfile.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     fhandle;
    __int64 fsize;

    // open binary file as read only. deny sharing write permissions. allow write permissions if new file
    if (_sopen_s(&fhandle, argv[1], _O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY, _SH_DENYWR, _S_IWRITE) == -1)
        werror_exit
    else if (fhandle == -1)
        werr_exit("\nERROR: file does not exist...\n")

    if (fsize = _filelengthi64(fhandle) == -1)
    {
        if (_close(fhandle) == -1)
            werror_exit
        werror_exit
    }

    if (_close(fhandle) == -1)
        werror_exit

    // write the file size to stdout
    wnum(fsize);

    return 0;
}

// fetch the string representation of the errno global variable and write it to stderr
void werror()
{
    char    bufstr[95];
    size_t  buflen = 95; // MSDN suggested number for errno string length

    strerror_s(bufstr, buflen, errno);
    _write(stderr, bufstr, (unsigned int)buflen);

    _set_errno(0);
}

// recursively write the ascii value of each digit in a number to stdout
void wnum(__int64 num)
{
    if (num / 10 == 0)
    {
        _write(stdout, &(num += 48), 1);
        return;
    }

    wnum(num / 10);
    _write(stdout, &((num %= 10) += 48), 1);
}
```

I have tried passing many different filepaths to `argv[1]` yet they all still show an `fsize` of 0. In all of those cases, `fhandle` was assigned a value of 3 after using `_sopen_s()` which indicates no errors when opening the files. I have verified the operation of `wnum()` and `werror()`. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Dumb question, but are you 1000% sure wnum works? have you tried doing sprintf instead?

Comment: @yhyrcanus yes it does work. I forgot to mention in my question that I was trying to avoid `stdio.h` functions and stick to `io.h` functions only. `fsize` is assigned a value of 0 after `_filelengthi64()` as seen from the debugger in visual studio.

Comment: regarding: `if (_sopen_s(&fhandle, argv[1], _O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY, _SH_DENYWR, _S_IWRITE)`  doesn't that `_S_IWRITE` say your trying to open the file for write?  If so, then, naturally, the file would be truncated to 0 length

Comment: @user3629249 That is the `pmode` parameter of the function which is used to set the permission settings of the file if it is a new file indicated by the `_O_CREATE` flag. I am not using this flag so that parameter is ignored. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w64k0ytk.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_filelengthi64(fhandle)` doesn't return 0. The expression `_filelengthi64(fhandle) == -1`, however, will (assuming a successful call), which is then assigned to `fsize`. You are ignoring the [C operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), dictating that `==` has higher precedence than `=`. You will have to use parentheses to change the precedence:

```
if ((fsize = _filelengthi64(fhandle)) == -1)
{
    ...
```

If you want to reduce the amount of mental energy required to write (and especially read) code, it is generally a good idea to isolate normal code logic from error handling, e.g.:

```
// Normal code flow
fsize = _filelengthi64(fhandle);
// Error handling code
if (fsize == -1)
{
    ...
```

Comment: *it is generally a good idea to isolate normal code logic from error handling*  Indeed.  This question is just **another** example of why stuffing an assignment and error checking into one conditional clause is really just bad code.  "Brevity of code" does not mean "stuff as much crap as you can into one line until you can't understand what you wrote", which is clearly what happened here.